# How to overwrite X2GO_NXAGENT_DEFAULT_OPTIONS from client side using windows?

Tags: windows, session, ubuntu

I am having a problem starting an X2go client session to an Ubuntu work station. Basically, the x2Go-agent does not scale down to fit my client's side screen resolution. Thus, I cannot reach Ubuntu control panels, switch between programs, etc.

I use the newest download of the x2Go windows client, version 4.0.2.0. I use session settings that worked previously, but we have had an update recently. First, I tried playing around with the session screen size, but none of the options gives a reasonable view. I searched for similar issues and found a [bug entry](http://bugs.x2go.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=96) that suggests disabling some NX-extension by **commenting** the line

```
X2GO_NXAGENT_DEFAULT_OPTIONS+=" -extension XFIXES"
```

in `etc/x2go/x2goagent.options`.

This is not possible for me without appropriate admin rights. Instead, I found out from the [changelog](https://www.mail-archive.com/x2go-dev@lists.berlios.de/msg04541.html) that the above option can be overwritten from client-side, but it doesn't say how:

> Introduce /etc/x2go/x2goagent.options to allow overriding x2goagent
>         options. This new configuration file specifies default options that
>         clients can override.

The [man-page](http://code.x2go.org/doc/x2goclient/man/man1/x2goclient.1.html) of the x2Go client doesn't tell, either. It doesn't seem that there is a command line option to redefine the variable during execution.

Here is my question: Does anyone know how to overwrite the above option from a windows x2go client side?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the problem is not fixable from the Windows side. But you can fix the issue by disabling "kcreen" in your KDE where the x2go server is running. See [the following citation](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:faq:start#ubuntu_s_and_fedora_s_kde_won_t_resize_the_desktop_to_the_window_size_requested_by_x2go_client_how_can_i_fix_this):

> In general, this is not a bug. Using two applications that handle display resolution is not supported

Comment: Thanks a lot for digging into this.